# How to remove imported blender keymap?

Tags: keymap

[image]

I imported keymap settings from 2.8 to 3.3 with filename blender.py (2nd preset) but it didn't work very well so I tried to remove it. However I couldn't delete the imported preset later on, Blender keep warning "unable to remove default presets". I have tried uninstall-install but it was still there. Is there a way to remove this duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Found it accidentally while looking up on resetting userpref.blend, the imported keymap file is located in here:

```
[drive]:\Users\[profile]\AppData\Roaming\[install directory]\[#version]\scipts\presets\keyconfig
```

in mine, it is something like:
C:\Users\LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\presets\keyconfig

so I deleted the imported keymap file (blender.py) and now the duplicate is removed.